# How do I smooth out the edges of a closed line similar to d3's curveCardinal method implementation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, d3.js, scipy

I have a few data points that I am connecting using a closed line plot, and I want the line to have smooth edges similar to how the **curveCardinal** methods in d3 do it. [Link Here](http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/c25a147970def2b02d8c7c2719dc7502)

Here's a minimal example of what I want to do:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0.5, 0.13, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5])
y = np.array([1.0, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.scatter(x, y)
```

Now, I'd like to smooth out/interpolate the line similar to d3's curveCardinal methods. Here are a few things that I've tried.

```py
from scipy import interpolate

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)  
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 100), tck)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(xi, yi, '-b')
ax.plot(x, y, 'k')
ax.scatter(x[:2], y[:2], s=200)
ax.scatter(x, y)
```

The result of the above code is not bad, but I was hoping that the curve would stay closer to the line when the data points are far apart (I increased the size of two such data points above to highlight this). Essentially, have the curve stay close to the line.

Using interp1d (has the same problem as the code above):

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = [0.5, 0.13, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5]
y = [1.0, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0]

orig_len = len(x)
x = x[-3:-1] + x + x[1:3]
y = y[-3:-1] + y + y[1:3]

t = np.arange(len(x))
ti = np.linspace(2, orig_len + 1, 10 * orig_len)

kind='cubic'
xi = interp1d(t, x, kind=kind)(ti)
yi = interp1d(t, y, kind=kind)(ti)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xi, yi, 'g')
ax.plot(x, y, 'k')
ax.scatter(x, y)
```

I also looked at the Chaikins Corner Cutting algorithm, but I don't like the result.

```py
def chaikins_corner_cutting(coords, refinements=5):
    coords = np.array(coords)

    for _ in range(refinements):
        L = coords.repeat(2, axis=0)
        R = np.empty_like(L)
        R[0] = L[0]
        R[2::2] = L[1:-1:2]
        R[1:-1:2] = L[2::2]
        R[-1] = L[-1]
        coords = L * 0.75 + R * 0.25

    return coords


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, 'k', linewidth=1)
ax.plot(chaikins_corner_cutting(x, 4), chaikins_corner_cutting(y, 4))
```

I also, superficially, looked at Bezier curves, matplotlibs PathPatch, and Fancy box implementations, but I couldn't get any satisfactory results.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited the comment to add why I don't like the current results. I want the curve to stay close to the line. The only part of the figure that has a real physical meaning are the edges, it's just the appearance of the plot that I want to improve (while preserving the physically important information). So getting the curve to thread the line as close as possible would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Did you try the same points with d3? I doubt they would give a different result there.

Comment: Yes, the inspiration comes from a d3.js radar chart that I saw. Here is a quick [codepen](https://codepen.io/besian/pen/pXgRmW?editors=1000) I made to showcase that.
The data points of the figure are at the bottom of the page and you can see that regardless of how you change them the curve still looks great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's how I ended up doing it. I decided to introduce new points between every two existing data points. The following image shows how I am adding these new points. Red are data that I have. Using a convex hull I calculate the geometric center of the data points and draw lines to it from each point (shown with blue lines). Divide these lines twice in half and connect the resulting points (green line). The center of the green line is the new point added.

[image]

Here are the functions that accomplish this:

```py
def midpoint(p1, p2, sf=1):
    """Calculate the midpoint, with an optional 
    scaling-factor (sf)"""
    xm = ((p1[0]+p2[0])/2) * sf
    ym = ((p1[1]+p2[1])/2) * sf
    return (xm, ym)
```

```py
def star_curv(old_x, old_y):
    """ Interpolates every point by a star-shaped curve. It does so by adding
    "fake" data points in-between every two data points, and pushes these "fake"
    points towards the center of the graph (roughly 1/4 of the way).
    """

    try:
        points = np.array([old_x, old_y]).reshape(7, 2)
        hull = ConvexHull(points)
        x_mid = np.mean(hull.points[hull.vertices,0])
        y_mid = np.mean(hull.points[hull.vertices,1])
    except:
        x_mid = 0.5
        y_mid = 0.5

    c=1
    x, y = [], []
    for i, j in zip(old_x, old_y):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(j)
        try:
            xm_i, ym_i = midpoint((i, j),
                                  midpoint((i, j), (x_mid, y_mid)))

            xm_j, ym_j = midpoint((old_x[c], old_y[c]),
                                  midpoint((old_x[c], old_y[c]), (x_mid, y_mid)))

            xm, ym = midpoint((xm_i, ym_i), (xm_j, ym_j))
            x.append(xm)
            y.append(ym)
            c += 1
        except IndexError:
            break


    orig_len = len(x)
    x = x[-3:-1] + x + x[1:3]
    y = y[-3:-1] + y + y[1:3]


    t = np.arange(len(x))
    ti = np.linspace(2, orig_len + 1, 10 * orig_len)

    kind='quadratic'
    xi = interp1d(t, x, kind=kind)(ti)
    yi = interp1d(t, y, kind=kind)(ti)

    return xi, yi
```

Here's how it looks:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

x = [0.5, 0.13, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5]
y = [1.0, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0]

xi, yi = star_curv(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xi, yi, 'g')

ax.plot(x, y, 'k', alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter(x, y, color='r')
```

[image]

The result is especially noticeable when the data points are more symmetric, for example the following x, y values give the results in the image below:

```py
x = [0.5, 0.32, 0.34, 0.5, 0.66, 0.65, 0.5]
y = [0.71, 0.6, 0.41, 0.3, 0.41, 0.59, 0.71]
```

Comparison between the interpolation presented here, with the default interp1d interpolation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would create another array with the vertices extended in/out or up/down by about 5%. So if a point is lower than the average of the neighbouring points, make it a bit lower still.

Then do a linear interpolation between the new points, say 10 points/edge. Finally do a spline between the second last point per edge and the actual vertex. If you use Bezier curves, you can make the spline come in at the same angle on each side.

It's a bit of work, but of course you can use this anywhere.

Comment: I ended up following a different approach, but with a similar idea in mind. 
Increasing the number of points in the direction that gives me the interpolation that I want. Initially, I tried to generate points for each edge from a normal distribution with loc=edges, but that would have been too much work. I am however, quite satisfied with the method I ended up going for, at least so far. 
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Ah, I was visualizing it differently. Your diagrams make perfect sense and it looks like a good result. Thanks for updating.